# How to open a file in Notepad from a batch file depending on greatest number in file name?

Tags: batch-file

Please help me to open a file like `app.log.192192193` in Notepad using batch script from the below scenario.

```
c:\Abcd\app\log
  app.log.123123123 --- 200KB      same date time
  app.log.143143143 --- 20000KB    same date time
  app.log.192192193 --- 0KB        same date time
```

In simple words all files were of same date and time and differ in size and file name.
Need to open the file which has greater value in the file name, i.e. 1921192193 > 143143143

Comment: Have you already tried anything?

Comment: Tried start wgnplot.exe "c:\New Folder\New Text Document.log". And it errored out.

Comment: @Jawahar - my answe has been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my batch solution with less lines and which definitely works for the example file names.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set GreatestNumber=.0
for /F %%f in ('dir "C:\Abcd\app\log\app.log.*" /B 2^>nul') do (
   if "%%~xf" GTR "!GreatestNumber!" set "GreatestNumber=%%~xf"
)
if not "%GreatestNumber%" == ".0" (
   start "Notepad" %SystemRoot%\System32\Notepad.exe "C:\Abcd\app\log\app.log%GreatestNumber%"
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks @Mofi, ran the above script its perfect. Can you add some tweak to open the notepad to the end.

Comment: Notepad is started at end of batch file if there is at least one `app.log.*` file in directory "C:\Abcd\app\log\".

Answer (score 4):

Open the largest file.

```
@echo off
set log_dir=c:\log_dir
pushd "%log_dir%"

for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /o:s app.log.*') do (
    set "largest_log=%%~ff"
)

start notepad "%largest_log%"
```

**EDIT** - opens the file with the largest number in it's name

```
@echo off
set log_dir=c:\log_dir
pushd "%log_dir%"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "current_number=0"
for /f "tokens=3 delims=." %%f in ('dir /b /o:s app.log.*') do (
    if %%~f GTR !current_number! (
        set "current_number=%%f"
    )
)

start notepad "app.log.%current_number%"
```

Comment: Don't you need to to sort by name?   npocmaka's solution sorts by filesize.  The filenames will need to be the same length for this sort of solution, too. From the question: `greater value in the file name (1921192193 > 143143143)`

Comment: @foxidrive oouch.I missred the question.I thought that the largest file need to be open.I'll fix it.

Comment: Thanks both for pointing the miss, when i tried running the new script i'm getting a pop up like app.log.0 is not present. Do you want to create Yes No Cancel

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "mostnum="
SET "moststr=."
SET "dots=..........................................................."
FOR %%a IN ("%sourcedir%\app.log.*") DO (
 SET tempstr=%dots%%%~xa
 SET "tempstr=!tempstr:~-30!"
 IF !tempstr! gtr !moststr! (
  set "moststr=!tempstr!"
  SET mostnum=%%~xa
 )
)

ECHO(notepad "%sourcedir%\app.log%mostnum%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

You haven't told us how long your number may be or whether it may be variable-length. This should deal with up to 30 digits. Solutions using `gtr` but not padding the number assume that the length of the final numeric part is constant **and** nine digits or fewer.

The `notepad` command is merely `echo`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(notepad` to `notepad` to actually have notepad open the file.

Comment: Thanks @Magoo, the numbers are of length 10 digits. Its working fine. But the notepad is not opening at the end of the file.

Comment: Have you changed the `ECHO(notepad` to `notepad` as stated in the notes? Is `notepad.exe` in your `path`? What happens at the end?

Comment: Made the changes. No problem in opening the file.When the notepad opend the cursor is at the begining of the page, can this open the log file to the end of the page (Latest log).

Comment: As far as I can determine, notepad does not have such a facility - at least as part of the command-line options. I did find some vague references to running a macro or perhaps some tool like Autoit may be used. Google is your friend.